# Web Service Contingency Plan???? vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, soap

Im building a web service for different locations around the country.
At the moment, if one service goes down, it takes all the others with them and I cant view anything without commenting out the failed web service.

What can i do so in the event that a web service goes down, the others will carry on as usual and will still be viewable?

in the real world, I wouldnt be able to comment out the failing web service while the owner tries to fix it?

I havent tried anything yet, I dont know where to start.

Please help, I need this doing tonight.

Thanks

```
<script>

dim ws1 as new Proxy.Class
dim dt as new datatable
dt = ws1.Method

...Code Here...

dim ws2 as new Proxy.Class
dim dt2 as new datatable
dt2 = ws2.Method

...More Code...

merge
Display
</script>
```

There are about 7 services all in 1 sub
If 1 goes down, it takes all of them down.
how can i skip this 1 that goes down and still display the others that are working?

Comment: Have you looked at hosting your service on a cloud provider like Amazon Web Services or Google Cloud?!

Comment: The other thing you should look into is a "web proxy" that routes to "up" systems

Comment: its a university assignment. we have to use the university web space. if i used a 3rd party host and it went down, id be to blame and fail. but if the uni webspace goes down, im not to blame and dont fail. in my asmx i have a long list of services all being called in the same <script> tags. i want it to look at the service and instead of throwing a error, i want it to put "London service unavailable" in a label.

Comment: Then look at using a "web proxy" that redirects to one of the (currently available) locations

Comment: I think the question is being misunderstood... I think OP doesn't have **many** webservices in **many** different locations... he has **one** web application wich executes a different service depending on where the request comes from... am I right?

Comment: yea, one lot of code with many web services
ill put a bit of code up to try and give you a better idea.